# xslt grab value from other node

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have two xslt dynamic drop down boxes and need a test statement that will test if the other one has been used.

```
<xsl:template match="cat">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test = (if dog has already been selected)
        <select id="selectCAT">
           <option value="" onchange="submitCAT()">
           <option value="shorthair">
        </select>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <select id="selectCAT">
           <option value="">
           <option value="longhair">
        </select>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dog">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test = (if cat has already been selected)
        <select id="selectDOG">
           <option value="" onchange="submitDOG()">
           <option value="shorthair">
        </select>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <select id="selectDOG">
           <option value="">
           <option value="longhair">
        </select>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I pretty much have the two drop downs and only need it to call a function if the only one has already been selected. I just cannot figure out how to tell if the other drop down has been used.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post a XML sample?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure we can answer that unless you state how you are storing (in the xml) these facts. Personally, though, I think I'd just test it in javascript - i.e. ask selectDOG / selectCAT what options are selected and selectively submit.